# Is it a coincidence that The Munsters and The Addams Family both started in the same week?

Tags: distribution, the-addams-family, the-munsters

The TV shows from the 60's of [The Addams Family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Addams_Family) and [The Munsters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Munsters) have similar macabre themes and characters.

We know that the Addams family was originally a [cartoon in The New Yorker by Charles Addams](http://www.newyorker.com/cartoons/bob-mankoff/charles-addams).

Intriguingly enough - both shows [started in the same week](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/tvandradio/11102649/The-Addams-Family-v-The-Munsters.html) in September 1964.

My question is: **Is it a coincidence that the Munsters and the Addams family both started in the same week?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**No.**

CBS knew that that Addams family, already established through cartoons, was readily primed for a TV adaptation, and decided to [create a property out of it without the rights to its characters](http://www.paleycenter.org/the-addamses-vs-the-munsters/).

When ABC found out this was going to happen, they readily greenlit a series for the actual Addams family to finally be translated onto the screen. If it weren't for CBS' eagerness to make the show, the Addams family itself may never have been made.

The Addams family was well established, [and as it's script was written by Nat Perrin](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/tvandradio/11102649/The-Addams-Family-v-The-Munsters.html) (Who wrote for the Marx Brothers) CBS understood what tone the show would be in, and tried to replicate it.

Despite the Addams family being the progenitor, the Munsters actually received better ratings.

Comment: That's a great story - and it sounds right, but I'm not sure your reference is evidence of it. Have you got another reference?

Comment: sorry, those links were in the wrong places! corrected.

Comment: I love little tidbits like this, it will become handy when I become Jeopardy champion on my way to Ultimate Ruler of The World!!

Comment: @ScottGoodgame Commenting under a fake name, eh, Watson?

Comment: Really is my name.